# Cosa significa "come" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

I feel confused with the usage of "come" in several subtitles here, for example:

> Prendono come ausiliare il verbo *essere*.

Please let me know if I am wrong. I guess the subject of "prendono" are the following verbs. In addition, "ausiliare" is a noun here.

So what is the meaning of "come" in this example? It doesn't make sense with neither "how" nor "like". Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case: the Italian "come" must be interpreted as "in the role of".

As to the subject of "prendono" please see what Charo says in the comment to this answer.

As Charo pointed out to me:

> the subject [of "prendono"] in sentence *a* is molti verbi di movimento, molti verbi di stato in luogo, alcuni verbi intransitivi, i verbi riflessivi; in sentence *b* is i verbi transitivi, alcuni verbi intransitivi; in sentence *c* is alcuni verbi.

The meaning of the whole sentence is then:

The following verbs need "essere" as auxiliary verb.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I would say that the subject in sentence ***a*** is *molti verbi di movimento, molti verbi di stato in luogo, alcuni verbi intransitivi, i verbi riflessivi*; in sentence ***b*** is *i verbi transitivi, alcuni verbi intransitivi*; in sentence ***c*** is *alcuni verbi*.

Comment: @Charo thanks. I overlooked something.

Comment: Please, add whatever you want from my comment to your anwser: [comments are temporary](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and all relevant information should be on answers or questions.

Comment: @Charo done, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I have another question. Can I say "Prendono il verbo essere come ausiliare.", which is more similar to the word order of English?

Comment: @smartsheep Yes, you can. With that inverted order ("Prendono come ausiliare il verbo essere") readers expect in the second paragraph a difference on the verb that is used as auxiliary, as in fact is ("Prendono come ausiliare il verbo avere"), while with the linear order, that you mention ("Prendono il verbo essere come ausiliare"), readers may happen to expect in the second paragraph a difference on the role of the verb essere e.g. they may expect something like "Prendono il verbo essere come modale". But this in only a minor concern, not really a big deal.

Comment: @smartsheep Notice also that you can even say "Come ausiliare prendono il verbo essere", if you do not want to interrupt the regular word ordering without incurring in the said problem.

Comment: @thatsme Grazie mille!

Comment: @smartsheep di nulla :-)